# How to set 'no proxy' in clojure http request like we do in curl?

Tags: http, curl, clojure, proxy

I want to hit an api (GET request) in clojure inside open shift pod with "`no-proxy`" but it gives me 404 (resource not found) although I passed correct header (for authorisation inside open shift pod). Same request giving 200 by curl command with noproxy in pod terminal. Please suggest.

Using `Clojure API - clj-http.client`

Below is Clojure code which is not working (giving 404):

```
(defn get-toggles []   
   (let [options {:headers {:x-jwt-payload "valid-value-passed"}}
         response (client/get "correct-url" {:proxy-ignore-hosts "*" :proxy-port "*"} options)]))
```

Below is Curl hit inside pod terminal that is working fine (with noproxy only):`curl -i --noproxy "*" "any-correct-url" -H "x-jwt-payload :valid-value"`

Note: without "`noproxy`", we will get 401 thats why we are using it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code, there seems no way to create a request that specifically uses no proxy at all.

I once ran into the same problem and ended up using [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), a java library for making http requests and parsing HTML. I did not use the HTML parsing function, I sent requests to a Rest Api, but the Api of Jsoup is nice and well usable from Clojure. For example:

```
(ns something
  (import
   org.jsoup.Jsoup
   java.net.Proxy
   java.lang.Thread))

(defn api-call [url]
  (->
   (Jsoup/connect url)
   (.proxy (Proxy/NO_PROXY))
   (.ignoreContentType true)
   (.get)
   (.body)
   (.text)))
```

Comment: Thanks :) Can you please put example with header also in above clojure function. I will try with that code and will let you know the result.